# Michael Nielsen's NNDL chapter 1 about indices j and k swap why?

Tags: neural-network

I just read the Michael Nielsen's NNDL online book.

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

In chapter 1, he used a indices for weights k j in reverse order instead of j k. He mentioned the benefit is that it can represent the vector form. can someone prove that? why wouldn't we use normal order j k to represent vector form?

Comment: I can not find the paragraph, could you write the phrase where he mentions these "benefits"? Usually the indexes on weights indicate: from_neuron , to_neuron; sometimes in reverse, it depens on the formula.

Comment: Sorry my bad. It's just right before Equation 22. Here is the quote:  Since net.weights[1] is rather verbose, let's just denote that matrix ww. It's a matrix such that wjkwjk is the weight for the connection between the kthkth neuron in the second layer, and the jthjth neuron in the third layer. This ordering of the jj and kk indices may seem strange - surely it'd make more sense to swap the jj and kk indices around? The big advantage of using this ordering is that it means that the vector of activations of the third layer of neurons is: a′=σ(wa+b).(22)_